# FileGDB API for Visual Studio gives error?

Tags: error, visual-studio, file-geodatabase-api

I download API for vs 2008. When I try add reference VS show error:

[image]

What can I do?

Windows 7 64 bit

dll too for 64 bit

VS 2008

Comment: You just need to modify the solution to use the C++ library.